# My digitizing lines keep disappearing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, digitizing

I am having a really hard time digitizing roads in a map for an assignment in my GIS course. I follow the steps, I open editor, snapping, I open a window to create a new feature. But when I start digitizing, the lines I draw keep disappearing after I double click on them or click finish sketch. I use the auto complete polygon construction tool because I am not making an enclosed polygon I am just making lines along roads.

Does anyone know what issues might causing my lines to disappear and how I can fix them?

Comment: It sounds like you're outside your spatial domain, what are the coordinate systems of the map window and feature data source? What type of feature data source is it? Another possibility is that you have a definition query on the layer that isn't satisfied by default, I've seen that happen and the operator ended up with ~30 lines almost exactly on top of each other.

Comment: If you have already classified that theme, turn on the "all other values" category.

Comment: Your process is not clear, are you digitizing line or polygon (you said that your are "just making lines along roads"  but also that you are using the auto complete polygon tool) ? could you clarify

Comment: I had the same issue, problem solved is turn it on in the Vector menu at the top of the viewer and then hit the viewing Properties, ensure you turn it on checked for Points, or Arcs, or Polgyon... That will show up !